# FadeToggle with visibility hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get `#hi` to fadeOut. Right now, the fade isn't happening. The div just disappears.

```
setTimeout(function() {
     $('.project-link-1').css('visibility','hidden').hide().fadeOut(1000);       
}, 3000);

#hi {visibility:visible;}
```

I know if can just use `.animate` and `opacity:0`, but I'd like to keep IE compatibility.

Comment: @CRABOLO That didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using hide() then fade

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.project-link-1').fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')
  });
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-link-1">project-link-1</div>
```

---

If you just want to hide the element after fading

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.project-link-1').fadeOut(1000);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-link-1">project-link-1</div>
```